# Failed review audit on a question with very little information

Tags: discussion, review-audits, review-suspension

I was just review-banned after failing this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10309610

I voted to close it as being Too Broad, but also considered closing due to being Off-topic for the "Why isn't this code working?" with not enough information.

Regardless, I failed the audit for voting to close it, as there is, apparently, nothing wrong with the question.  What am I missing here?  Is this question truly not worthy of being closed?

Comment: I don't understand the technology the question is about, so i would have skipped it. Short, without a code snippet, doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't have enough information. Explaining that *"I'm using `-dataWithPDFInsideRect:` with an `NSView` that has many subviews"* may be sufficient to users *in the know* for that technology.

Comment: I suppose that does make sense - I thought about skipping it for that very reason that I'm not familiar with the technology, but after reading it, it  seemed overly light on the details...

Comment: not enough details though isn't a close reason, unless the lack of details make it unclear or too open to interpretation (err.. broad.)